# 2 devise problems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm new to devise, struggling with these problems

1. I'm using devise plus rpx_connectable plugin. How can I redirect the user to the page he/she was browsing after successful sign in. I've tried every possible solution here on stackoverflow, read the documentation, and unfortunately it doesn't work.
2. How could I make devise remember me after closing the browser and returning again, although I set config.remember_for = 2.weeks and it doesn't work too?

Comment: In the future, I would encourage you to post these as two distinct questions.

Comment: Will consider that in the future, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The default behavior of Devise is to redirect to the protected resource that was requested after sign in. I would be surprised if `rpx_connectable` plugin is preventing this. Are you sure it's not working -- this sounds silly, but I spent 30 minutes trying to find out how to implement it in the documentation before I realized it was the default behavior.
2. Are you clicking the `remember_me` checkbox on login? If you don't click that, the cookie defaults to expiring when the browser closes.

Comment: But how I could I set the cookie expiration date without explicitly click on a remember_me checkbox?